# Django: The form re-submission with different set of cookies is successful. This may imply that the form does not contain any CSRF countermeasures

Tags: django, forms, cookies, csrf-protection

I logedin on Computer A and computer B, I copy csrf from Computer A and change Computer B csrf with computer A csrf and submit Form, its successfully submited.
How i handle this kind of swinthuation.

Comment: What are you trying to prevent? I don't think you understand what CSRF is for.

Comment: Its Qualys Scan result.

Comment: Threat:
An effective CSRF (Cross-Site Request Forgery) countermeasure for forms is to include a hidden field with a random value specific to the user's current session. A form was detected that did not appear to contain an anti-CSRF token. This form was tested for susceptibility to a CSRF attack and determined to be vulnerable.

Comment: Impact:
CSRF vulnerabilities can be used by an attacker to force a user to submit requests to the Web application without the user's knowledge or approval. The vulnerability's impact depends on the the consequence of submitting a request within the context of the Web application.

Comment: Please post the version of django you are using, and the code that you are testing - otherwise your question is unanswerable.

Comment: Django version is 1.8.2

Comment: and i am talking about admin not for website, so its default code of django admin

Comment: if you feel you have found a security vulnerability, please report it directly to `security@djangoproject.com`.

Comment: i already e-mailed them, but no response

Comment: its possible to talk with you on Django  for some help ? kindly share your gmail address or any other id for chat @Burhan Khalid

Comment: Please clarify: Did you perform the requests while logged out, logged in to the same account on both machines, or what? Did you copy over anything (like cookies) aside from the CSRF token?

Answer (score 0):

This is by design. The comparison between the cookie CSRF token and the POST CSRF token is a server-side check but it's not against any stored server-side value. Remember that an attacker cannot steal a user's browser's CSRF cookie. "Stealing" or modifying your own token isn't a vulnerability.

Comment: If it were possible to use a token from one user to take action from another user's account, that would be a vulnerability. I don't know how Django's CSRF tokens are generated, so I don't know what the situation is in this case. If they're based on users, then this is secure only iff he's logged into the same account on both machines to make the request. If it's based on IP, then there exists a vulnerability but it's isolated to people behind the same IP so it's not as severe. If it's based on a cookie session token, there's a vulnerability if he didn't copy the cookies over.

Comment: (edit: Oh, you're a Django dev? Guess I don't need to explain this to you!) It [looks like](https://github.com/django/django/blob/2d28144c9519f4e4397c70f045c2b1d31437bf69/django/middleware/csrf.py) Django's CSRF tokens are random values stored in cookies. So copying a token from one machine to the other should not work, because it will not have the same cookies. Maybe the questioner just didn't have CSRF actually enabled for the view in question, somehow despite including a CSRF token in it.